# IE refuse to change array elements into text

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, arrays, internet-explorer

I have problem with my javascript code working on IE. I think I know exactly why it is working wrong, although I dont know how to change it.

Let me explain:

My code consist of small part of code inside $(document).ready() and a lot of inside $ajax.success(). The first part works normally, then I thought I have problem with ajax - that it simply dont work on IE. The error was:

Script65535 unexpected call to method or property access.
Jquery - 1.7.2.min.js line 5847, character 5

And line 5847 is APPEND function!!! It simply must work!

```
5844  append: function() {
5845    return this.domManip(arguments, true, function( elem ) {
5846        if ( this.nodeType === 1 ) {
5847            this.appendChild( elem );
5848        }
5849    });
5850  }
```

Then I found on google, that IE have problems when the multi-dimension array is changed to text. And only two appends in my ajax.success() function appends the content of arrays!

```
$('.display_info_here').append(tab_szablony[i][lang_number-2].toUpperCase()+'</br></br>');
```

I tried to change the array to text in another way, but it didnt worked

```
var arrr = tab_szablony[i][lang_number-2];
$('.display_info_here').append(arrr.toUpperCase()+'</br></br>');
```

It works on IE 9+, but not in 8 :(

Thanks for any help :)

Comment: Use your console to debug. Is variable 'arrr' expected result in IE8? Why call it 'arrr' when it seems to be a string?

Comment: I just named it arr, it can be string_to_append, my console only says that it is a problem in jquery